# Definite Integral using its McLaurin Series.

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, summation

I'm trying to solve the next integral, using its series. However, I got stuck in a very dumb way nearly at the end.

The infamous:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{cosh}(x)-1}{x}dx$$

First, the series of $\text{cosh}(x)$ is: $$\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=1+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}+\text{... etc}$$

Then I replaced the hiperbolic cosine with the series:

$$\int \frac{(1+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}+\text{...})-1}{x}dx$$

Reducing and solving the integral:

$$\int(\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{4!}+\frac{x^5}{6!}+\text{...})dx=\frac{x^2}{2*2!}+\frac{x^4}{4*4!}+\frac{x^6}{6*6!}+\text{...}+C$$

Then here is where I'm stuck:

$$\frac{x^2}{2*2!}+\frac{x^4}{4*4!}+\frac{x^6}{6*6!}+\text{...}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{2n(2n)!}$$

I'm cannot solve the last summation. It seems like a geometric series, but I'm unable to identify its parts, but since the orinigal integral was definite, I need the numerical value.

Is there a way? I feel really dumb when untangling series, and this one seems pretty easy...

TL;DR:
$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{cosh}(x)-1}{x}dx =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{2n(2n)!}|_0^1=?$

Comment: I don't know how to sum the series but after you integrate you don't have $x$ anymore; it should be replaced by 1.

Comment: @dom_miketa Yup, it ends as a 1/(2n)*(2n)!, but I need to entangle that.

Comment: What makes you think that is should be easy ?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chi.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x=0$, no problem. So, you are concerned by $$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{1}{2n(2n)!}$$ which will converge very fast as shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & S_p \\
 1 & 0.25000000000000000000 \\
 2 & 0.26041666666666666667 \\
 3 & 0.26064814814814814815 \\
 4 & 0.26065124834656084656 \\
 5 & 0.26065127590388007055 \\
 6 & 0.26065127607785304545 \\
 7 & 0.26065127607867238442 \\
 8 & 0.26065127607867537159 \\
 9 & 0.26065127607867538027 
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Beside the series expansion, you could start using $$I_a=\int_{0}^{a} \frac{\text{cosh}(x)-1}{x}dx=\text{Chi}(a)-\log (a)-\gamma$$ and, instead of using Taylor expansion (which is what you did), use Pade approximants built around $a=0$.

Among the simplest could be $$I_a\approx \frac{\frac{1}{4}a^2+\frac{11 }{4704}a^4}{1-\frac{19
   }{588}a^2+\frac{89 }{211680}a^4}\implies I_1\approx\frac{53415}{204929}\approx 0.2606512499 $$

Comment: Yeah, ~0.26 is the decimal answer I got from Wolfram. However, solving it this way only with pen and paper in a test is a pain in the ass.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I assure you that the downvote I wasn't from me.

Comment: @igan: ok, restructuring my comments.

Comment: The downvote is not deserved.

Comment: @igan The first three terms easily give the decent approximation $563/2160$.